# PDOException: SQLSTATE[]: <<Unknown error>>: 0 (SQLExecute[0] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:254)

Tags: php, oracle, pdo, bindparam

Trying to write to oracle calling a procedure using PHP but I get an unknown error.

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("

   begin :RESULT := STUD.IWS001FUN(:x_year, :x_stno, :x_bc, :x_bld, :x_status); end; 
  ");


    // Bind the output parameter    


 $sth->bindParam(':x_year',$academic_year, PDO::PARAM_INT ); 

 $sth->bindParam(':x_stno', $stno, PDO::PARAM_INT); 

 $sth->bindParam(':x_bc', $academic_block_code, PDO::PARAM_STR );

 $sth->bindParam(':x_bld', $BuildingCode, PDO::PARAM_INT ); 

 $sth->bindParam(':x_status', $Status, PDO::PARAM_STR);

 $sth->execute();
```

Comment: Your out bind, `:RESULT`, is unspecified.

Comment: What do youmean because i'm new in this

Comment: You need to bind to the `:RESULT` parameter: `$sth->bindParam(':RESULT', $result, PDO::PARAM_INT, 100);`. Double check what those last two parameters should be.